# Find Dynamics Contact Entity by value of field in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, dynamics-crm

I know that I can retrieve a contact by Guid like this:

```
var connection = new CrmConnection("CRM");
var service = new OrganizationService(connection);

var contact = service.Retrieve("contact", new Guid("ee07d029-e445-e511-8118-c4346bad4044"), new ColumnSet() { AllColumns = true });
```

...But that requires me to have the Guid of the contact. What if I want to find it by `emailaddress1` for instance?

I'm new to Dynamics and I've tried looking at the documentation *and* googling it without luck. 
I'm using the Online (hosted) version of Dynamics.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute("contact");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fullname", "emailaddress1");
query.Attributes.AddRange("emailaddress1");
query.Values.AddRange("test@test.com");
EntityCollection retrieved = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

[Sample: Retrieve multiple with the QueryByAttribute class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334708.aspx)

Comment: I would recommend the `QueryExpression` query type instead of `QueryByAttribute`. QueryByAttribute has very limited capabilities; the same and much more can be achieved by using QueryExpressions.